# Import problem "hibernate_sequence" table with Generation.type

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, sql-maven-plugin

So I'm trying to use a sql-maven-plugin to import my backup database.
I used annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE )` on my Entities, so my backup database has `hibernate_sequence` table with it.

How to avoid this error, but still use `@Id @GeneratedValue` ?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (populate-database) on project app: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" already exists -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Maybe i could some how generate the sequence table name myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is clear. hibernate_sequence already exists. your data is loaded already and you try to load data again. in this case, you can drop hibernate_sequence table or database for a fresh install.

```xml
  <execution>
    <id>create-db</id>
    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>execute</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:yourdb</url>
      <!-- no transaction -->
      <autocommit>true</autocommit>
      <sqlCommand>DROP SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence</sqlCommand>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Comment: This gives: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (populate-database) on project app: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" already exists -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I removed `TABLE` and replaced it with `SEQUENCE` then it works.. but of course JDBC can't copy things :(